# Does The Prisoner have a 'canonical' running order?

Tags: the-prisoner

I just finished watching the box set of *The Prisoner* and I was also reading the [reviews on the AV Club website](http://www.avclub.com/tvclub/tvshow/the-prisoner,84/), because I like reading reviews of things. I noticed that the episode order in the reviews was different to the order on the DVD.

Apparently, there's some disagreement about what the correct order of the episodes should be. Has there ever been a 'canonical' running order, and, if not, does it even matter?

Answer (score 7):

My personal opinion is that the running order isn't particularly important so long as you watch *Arrival* first and *Fall Out* last. Wikipedia [lists all the episodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Prisoner_episodes#Episode_list) with various permutations of running order.

I think the ITC order is the nearest you'll get to an "official" running order, this is the order in which the episodes were intended to be broadcast in the UK and is the order that they were broadcast in the US (except that Living in Harmony wasn't broadcast). I believe this is also the running order for my DVD boxset (Region 2).